# Produce following asterisk using two for loops

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, char, nested-loops

I need to produce following pattern using two for loops.

a 
aa 
aaa 
aaaa 
aaaaa 
aaaaaa 
aaaaaaa

I have try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    a = 7;
    for (int i = 1;i <= a;i++) {
        cout << "" << endl;
        for (int i = 1;i <= a;i++) {
            cout << "*";
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is 7 characters in seven rows :(

Comment: Try using a different name for the loop control variable of your inner loop, and limiting it by the value of the outer loop control variable.

Comment: @FredLarson Thank you very much, it works

Comment: Either of you (Ricky97 or @FredLarson) please make an answer, to get this out of the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the task can be done using only one loop.  For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        const char c = '*';

        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int n;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) or ( n == 0 ) ) break;

        std::cout << '\n';

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( i + 2 ) << std::setfill( c ) << '\n'; 
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6

*
**
***
****
*****
******

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

*
**
***
****
*****

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

*
**
***
****

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

*
**
***

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

*
**

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

As for your code then the inner loop outputs exactly 7 characters '*'

```
    for (int i = 1;i <= a;i++) {
        cout << "*";
    }
```

So what you do is what you get.

You could write the inner loop for example the following way

```
    for (int j = 0;j < i; j++) {
        cout << "*";
    }
```